# How to create LAN of Virtual machine?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, lan

I have 2 virtual machines in the same physical machine [using libvirt/KVM]. How can I create a lan with these 2 machines? Host and the guests are running ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution myself. I created an additional NIC in both the VMs and configured the ip of the new network interfaces. Should I leave my question so that others can benifit or should I vote to delete?

Comment: It's fine to answer your own question, so leave it here for others' reference. Also, mark your answer as 'accepted' too.